# Remove index.html from URL. Works when served from other server

Tags: angularjs, jetty, osgi, apache-karaf

I'm hoping someone will be kind enough and able to help me:

I have `$location.html5Mode(true)` & `$locationProvider.hashPrefix()` both set and when I run a simple web server from my app's `dist` folder the `index.html` is removed from the URL.

But when I serve this web-app from my container I get `http://localhost:8080/ui/index.html`

I've tried setting various settings in Jetty.xml, my WAB's web.xml, etc, but to no affect.

I'm a little light in specifics as our configuration is quite complex. However, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Keir